# dhcp won't stop

Tags: linux, dhcp

I set up a static ip for my linux box but DHCP still seems to run and changes my hostname and resolv.conf From what I understood just setting the iface to static should keep that from happening. I also did a "apt-get -y remove isc-dhcp-client dhcp3-client dhcpcd" but still no luck.

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0 eth0:1

iface eth0 inet static
 address 66.228.49.254
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 66.228.49.1

iface eth0:1 inet static
 address 192.168.169.183
 netmask 255.255.128.0
```

Ubuntu 11.04, Suggestions?

Comment: Please post the output of `ps wwaux|grep dhc|grep -v grep`.

Comment: root      2092  0.0  0.1   8428   556 ?        Ss   Oct19   0:00 /sbin/dhcpcd-bin -Y -N -H eth0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/etc/default/dhcpcd was set to write resolv.conf and set the host name. Changing both to "no" fixed the issue.

Comment: This and the running process are hints that you never disabled the dhcpcd-service in the runlevels.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually killed dhcpd so it was still running.

All you needed to do was kill it.